# How to sum amount weekly, monthly and yearly wise in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table. I want to get the sum of my order price in weekly, monthly and yearly wise in single query. How can I do that?

This is very easy if I separate query. My Query is:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS weekly_price FROM orders WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);        
SELECT SUM(price) AS monthly_price FROM orders WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
SELECT SUM(price) AS yearly_price FROM orders WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Please help me and write your answer that how to get my `weekly_price`, `monthly_price` and `yearly_price` in one query?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a inner  join of the subselect

```
    select t1.weekly_price, t2.monthly_price, t3.yearly_price
    from (  
          SELECT 1 as key, SUM(price) AS weekly_price 
          FROM orders 
          WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    ) t1 
    inner join (      
        SELECT 1 as key, SUM(price) AS monthly_price 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ) t2 on t1.key = t2.key
    inner join  ( 
        SELECT 1 as key, SUM(price) AS yearly_price 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    } t3 on t1.key = t3.key
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `CASE WHEN` in the `SUM()`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN orders.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN orders.price ELSE 0 END) AS weekly_price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN orders.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN orders.price ELSE 0 END) AS monthly_price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN orders.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN orders.price ELSE 0 END) AS yearly_price 
FROM 
    orders;
```